# Maintain the duplicates in the sum of array integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I wrote a program to:

1. ***Print the new array of elements***
2. ***Print the sum of all elements (or integers)***

Actually, I got it right, however, the little problem is, I want to maintain all the duplicates (still within the range of **four largest elements**). Here's what I mean:

*Take an array of numbers:* **[4,5,-2,3,1,2,6,6]**

The four largest numbers are **4,5,6,6**. And their sum is **4+5+6+6=21**

**What the code is doing (not good):**

Instead of getting **"6,6,5,4"** as (described above), the code is printing **"6,5,4,3"** with the sum as **18**.

**ALSO,** when there are only four elements [with or without duplicates] as in **[1,1,1,-5]**,
let it just add ALL elements. You guessed it, the sum of all elements is **-2**

How do I order the program to print the necessary duplicate(s) to make the four largest integers?

Here's my code...

```js
var arr = new Array(4,5,-2,3,1,2,6,6);
// var arr = new Array(1,1,1,-5);

// var largArr = new Array();

function largest() {

    largArr = Array(0, 0, 0, 0)

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] > largArr[0]) {

            largArr[0] = arr[i];

        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] > largArr[1] && arr[i] < largArr[0]) {

            largArr[1] = arr[i];

        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] > largArr[2] && arr[i] < largArr[1]) {

            largArr[2] = arr[i];

        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] > largArr[3] && arr[i] < largArr[2]) {

            largArr[3] = arr[i];

        }

    }
    console.log(largArr[0], largArr[1], largArr[2], largArr[3]);
    console.log(largArr[0] + largArr[1] + largArr[2] + largArr[3]);
}

largest();
```

I believe there is a genius out there who can help me solve this :)

Comment: what is the expected result for `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`?

Comment: I think by now you should know the answer: 6+6+6+6=24. Plus, I re-edited this post with the aim of specifying exactly what the program should do.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the top four and filter the original array.

```js
function get4Largest(array) {
    const top4 = [...array].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 4);
    return array.filter(v => {
        if (top4.includes(v)) {
            top4.splice(top4.indexOf(v), 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

console.log(get4Largest([4, 5, -2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6]));
```

A different approach by keeping indices.

```js
function get4Largest(array) {
    return array
        .map((v, i) => [v, i])
        .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a)
        .slice(0, 4)
        .sort(([, a], [, b]) => a - b)
        .map(([v]) => v);
}

console.log(get4Largest([4, 5, -2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want sum of largest four numbers then you can easily do with [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 4).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
```

```js
const numbers = [4, 5, -2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6];

const result = numbers
    .sort((a, b) => b - a)
    .slice(0, 4)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) methods of an array like so:

```js
function sumMaxValues (maxLength, values) {
  return values
    .sort((v1, v2) => v1 > v2 ? -1 : 1)
    .slice(0, maxLength)
    .reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0)
}

console.log(
  sumMaxValues(4, [4, 5, -2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 10]),
)
```

**Edit:** I fixed, a bug that @gog pointed out. The root cause of a problem was that `sort` when invoked without a compareFn then "the array elements are converted to strings, then sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value."(sort [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

Comment: Try adding `10` to your input array.

Comment: Thanks @gog, I fixed a bug and added a comment about the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want to have a classical type of solution, that avoids modern javascript methods, here's one

```js
const arr = Array(4, 5, -2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6);
//const arr = Array(1, 1, 1, -5);

function largest(){
    const largArr = Array(-1/0, -1/0, -1/0, -1/0);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < largArr.length; j++){
            if(arr[i] > largArr[j]){
                for(let k = largArr.length - 2; k >= j; k--){
                    largArr[k + 1] = largArr[k];
                }
                largArr[j] = arr[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    let sum = 0;
    for(let j = 0; j < largArr.length; j++){
        if(largArr[j] === -1/0){
            largArr[j] = 0;
        }
        sum += largArr[j];
    }
    console.log(largArr, sum);
}

largest();
```

`-1/0` stands for minus infinity (there can be no smaller number); you may also use `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` for it. If it's too exotic for your needs, replace `-1/0` with any number you are certain is less than any possible number in the array (that however, cannot be zero, since you allow negative numbers also).